# Firestore duplicate (empty) doc ID when setting doc ID using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

There seems to be a difference when I set a javascript variable "directly" as this (option 1):

```
const restaurant_name = "mcdonalds";
```

vs reading it in from innerHTML (option 2):

```
const restaurant_name = restaurant_name.innerHTML;
```

What I want to do here is to use the variable in my doc_ref to create a new Firestore subcollection under the appropriate restaurant name:

```
const doc_ref = firestore.collection("restaurants").doc(restaurant_name ).collection("reviews").doc("user1")
```

This works fine with option 1.

With option 2 however, Firestore creates the subcollection under a completely new empty document with the same ID as the already existing one ("mcdonalds").

Yes, you read that right - I have 2 documents with the same ID in my collection!

Here is the full snippet:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const restaurant_name = restaurant_name.innerHTML;
    const doc_ref = firestore.collection("restaurants").doc(restaurant_name ).collection("reviews").doc("user1")
    $('#buttonLike').on('click',function(){
        doc_ref.set(
            {"rating":'10'}
            );
     }
 );
```

My only idea so far was that the variable gets stored as some weird HTML-type with option 2. However, I got the same results when explicitly converting the variable with ToString.

Comment: What is the exact value of `restaurant_name`? Log it or use a debugger to find the value at runtime.

Comment: Using `console.log` I could see that it's the same ("mcdonalds") which is also reflected in the Firestore console since there is now one more document with the same ID ("mcdonalds").

Comment: It's not possible to have more than one document with the same ID in a collection.  Document ID must be unique per collection.  So I'm not sure what you're seeing here.

Comment: But that's what's happening! I invite you to hook this codepen to a firestore db, you should see what I am seeing (just create a "mcdonalds" document before adding the review): https://codepen.io/tgel0/pen/WNeRNPd